# NotSupportedException was unhandled - but why?

Tags: wpf, exception, datagrid, dispatcher

I am getting an exception and I cannot see why I am getting this.
I want to update a `DataGrid` with data from SQL.

The problem seems to be connected to my `ObservableCollection`..

Here is the code:

```
private void Refresh()
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        List<DatabaseEntry> entries = GetBrokenJobs();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
           UpdateUi(entries);
        });
    }).Start();
}

private void UpdateUi(List<DatabaseEntry> entries)
{
    Jobs.Clear();//<== !!! Exception origin !!!
    foreach (var jobName in entries.SelectMany(x => x.JobBezeichnung as string).ToList())
    {
       Jobs.Add(jobName.ToString());
    }
}
```

The Exception is saying I cannot modify the "SourceCollection" when I am not on Dispatcher-Thread...

But I am Invoking the calling method on the Dispatcher ?!

What am I missing here ? Where is the fault ?

Comment: You can only update the observablecollection from the UI-dispatcher. You start a new thread use the dispatcher of the thread. that is not equal to the dispatcher of the ui

Comment: So when initializing my Viewodel can I add a static Dispatcher of the UI-Thread and then take that one ?

Comment: @Jehof you were right ^^ I solved it. I took the original Dispatcher of the UI-Thread

Comment: That said, you don't need a Thread at all. All your thread does is invokes the method in UI thread. You can just do it without the thread.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I want to do the SELECT in background cause it takes some time ... and freezes the UI... The actual UI-Update needs to be on the dispatcher ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run on UI thread like this

```
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
 {
    UpdateUi(entries);
 });
```

Comment: oh nice :D seems to be a better solution than mine ^^

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a static variable in my ViewModel:

```
public static Dispatcher UI_Dispatcher { get; set; }
```

then in my ViewModel:

```
public MainViewModel(Main window)
{
    UI_Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; //Since we are on the UI-Thread when passing this piece of code this is the right Dispatcher
}
```

Later I just Invoked on the `UI_Dispatcher.Invoke()`.